# Interchange of differentiation and integration sign.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing, partial-derivative, contour-integration

Let $f:\Omega\to \mathbb C$ be a function (where $\Omega$ is an open set) and suppose $\phi:\mathbb C\times \Omega\to \mathbb C$ be a function such that $f(z)=\int_C \phi(\zeta,z)d\zeta$ where $C$ is a simple closed curve.I want to prove that if $f$ is differentiable and $\phi$ is differentiable with respect to $z$ partially,then $f'(z)=\int_C\frac {\partial \phi}{\partial z}(\zeta,z)d\zeta$.I want to use this result to find the expression for $n$-th derivative of a holomorphic function $f$.I have already shown that if $f$ is holomorphic then $f'$ is holomorphic and from here it follows that $f$ is infinitely many times differentiable.Now,I have shown that $f'(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)^2}d\zeta$ for all points $z$ in the interior of the simple closed contour $C$.Now if I could prove the result,then I can show that $f''(z)=\frac{2!}{2\pi i}\int \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)^3}d\zeta$ and $f'''=...$ and $f''''=...$ and so on.Can someone help me prove this result.I would also appreciate an answer that provides sufficient conditions for interchange of differentiation and integration sign so that I can apply it to the above expression of $f'(z)$.

Comment: This is a consequence of Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem. See for example theorem 4.4.3 in [this paper](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/~richardt/MA2224/MA2224-ch4.pdf).

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I want an elementary proof of this fact that does not make use of measure theory.

Comment: What theorems do you know about the continuity of $x \mapsto \int f(x,t) dt$ when $ (x,t) \mapsto f(t,x)$ is supposed to be continuous? And what does it mean that you *don't want to make use of measure theory*? That you only know Riemann integration? Or to rephrase my question, what integration theory are you using?

Comment: An elementary proof is to show that the difference quotients converge uniformly. Using the fundamental theorem of calculus, one can show that this happens under very mild hypothesis on phi. The main ingredient is that a continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous.